# Plain text passwords in Ruby on Rails using Restful_Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, rest

If I use restful_authentication in my ruby on rails app are passwords transfered between the broswer and the server in paintext? And if so how worried should I be about it?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need to be worried if you are not hosting it over HTTPS... because if it is straight HTTP, then yes it is being passed in plaintext.

I don't know Rails specifically, but I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with whether you host it via HTTP or HTTPS.

Edit: I found [this link](http://blog.caboo.se/articles/2007/4/21/sample-rails-app-branch-with-ssl) which apparently provides an example Rails app over HTTPS.

Further Edit: Here is [another link](http://weeatbricks.com/2007/10/31/how-to-use-a-rails-app-with-https/) discussing HTTPS with Rails.

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned about the privacy of passwords (and [you should](http://www.betterthansimple.com/blog/2008/06/26/always-encrypt-passwords/) be), you will also want to add this line to your ApplicationController:

```
filter_parameter_logging :password
```

Otherwise the passwords will end up in plain text in your log files.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication with plain text can be done with CHAP style protocols. Is that possible over HTTP?

I'm asking, because I think that it would need some state on the server to foil replay-attacks - state on the server is something to be eliminated with RESTful architectures, right?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely have a look at the bcrypt gem. It will hash all passwords for you.